# Example of mask with tcomb-form-native

Tags: forms, react-native, textinput, tcomb-form-native

Is there an example of adding a mask to a tcomb-form-native on React Native?

How can I create a custom template to handle this ? https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form-native/issues/274

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is on this gist

https://gist.github.com/sibelius/c564ded5bfd39534cf035e0460f2ee9a

using https://github.com/benhurott/react-native-masked-text